# sets in the classical cantor space and how do they look in $2^{\mathbb N}$?

Tags: general-topology

Classical cantor = $C$ and $K = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$. $A_{n} = \left[\dfrac{1}{ 2^{2n-1}}, \dfrac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\right]\cap C$. Then $A_{n}$ in  $K$ is ?

Comment: That's a curious definition of $A_n$. It sounds like this is part of a larger problem. Could you please provide some context?

Comment: If by *classical Cantor space* you mean the middle-thirds Cantor set, your intervals $A_n$ have no natural relationship to it. Are you sure that they're correctly defined here?

Comment: Oops, you are right there was a typo and I have corrected now. Thanks

Comment: This is a little better, but not much. $A_1$ is the set of sequences with first term $1$, but $A_n$ for $n>1$ is ugly. If you're looking for the centres of the deleted intervals, they're at $$\frac{2k+1}{2\cdot3^m},\quad k=0,\dots,3^m-1\;.$$ (To make sure that I see an edit, leave a comment starting `@Brian`.)